# Finite State Machine Design for Entering/Exiting Door Sensor

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, circuit-design, state-machines, synchronous

I have attached an image of the assignment. I don't need to physically build it, just draw it using flip flops, mulitplexers, and logic gates. Not sure where to start at all. I appreciate any pointers and help.

[image]

Comment: Not sure, but does ClockEnable (CE) act like submitting whether it is up or down?

Comment: That's what I'm getting from the question Bradman.  To me it looks as though you could use D-Types to make a shift register then when all the outputs of the D-Types are the right value you set the direction and then set ClockEnable then clear the D-Types which basically goes back to the INIT state, the assumption being that the pattern changes on every clock.

Comment: One thing that doesn't make sense is that the FSM box doesn't show a Clock input, only a and b.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to implement a [Mealy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mealy_machine) [Finite State Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) using the "One-Hot" method.  Basically this means you need one FF for each state.  You have 5 states so you need 5 FF.  You have 2 outputs which determine the current "state".  The next state is determined by the 2 inputs and the current state.  State transitions occur on the rising edge of the clock I assume.

The format the author uses in the State Diagram for signals is AB/(CE UD')

The FSM provides the "control" for the circuit determining the next state to occur when a clock event happens.

We need to implement the FSM shown above.  This is done by looking at the State Diagram and all of the "arrows" entering each state.

So for instance, you will be at state "INIT" if the asynchronous signal "START" is asserted.  There are 5 more arrows entering INIT so we need logic for each of these five which is done with sum of products.

INIT = START + (INIT)A'B'*(CE') + R1*A'B'*(CE') + R2*A'B'*(CE)*UD' + L1*A'B'(CE') + L2*A'B'(CE)*(UD')'

The previous statement says that you will be in state "INIT" if any of the 6 conditions are met. The ' "tick" marks after a signal refer to the NOT or inverted signal.  The "*" refers to logic AND.  The "+" refers to logic OR.  The "=" is an assignment into the input of the the D-FF which corresponds to the INIT state.

Next, we have to use these states to keep track of how many students enter the room with a Up/Down counter.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! You have described *what* a Mealy one-hot machine is, but have not answered the actual question, which is *how* to generate the logic for it from the state diagram. And what "shift register" are you talking about anyway?

Comment: We need to implement the FSM shown above.  This is done by looking at each sate and all of the "arrows" entering each state.  So for instance, you will be at state "INIT" if the asynchronous signal "START" is asserted.

Comment: Add the additional material to your answer (see the `edit` button?). But you still haven't said how the arrows in the diagram become logic signals feeding the FFs. Give an example for at least one state.